# IF another cell = "X" then highlight this cell rule

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Looking for some help with my rental property analysis spreadsheet.  I have different criteria when evaluating a single family residence as compared to a duplex or triplex.  I analyze properties by how many doors they have.  My main evaluation criteria is $100 or more of cash flow per units.  So if it's a single family, I'm looking for $100+ cash flow, or if it's a duplex $200+ cash flow, etc.  I like to see the cash flow cell highlighted in GREEN or RED when it does/does not meet these conditions.  I've managed to get cell J5 to show 200 for a duplex and 100 for a single family.  Can someone help me with the rule I'd need in cell H5?  It should go something like "If J5=100 then H5=>100 highlight green or H5<100 highlight red" or "If J5=200 then H5=>200 highlight green or H5<200 highlight red".

[image]

Thank you a ton in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will result in two separate rules.

---

Use the `format only cells that contain` option under new formatting rules:

[image]

You can set "greater than or equal to" for your first rule, compared to `J5`... you don't need to state specifically "200" or "100" as that will be dictated by `J5`.  This would be the green fill.

Your second rule on the SAME CELL will be "Less than" `J5`, which would be your red fill.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Cyril, that makes sense but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason.   I posted a picture in another answer reply.  Let me know if you can't see it.

Comment: @brandonw The formula may be causing an issue... try using `=If(H15="Duplex",200,100)`, assuming you only have duplex or single family home. This will allow those values to show up as numbers, not a text-string.  Essentially, drop the quotation marks around the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzELu.png)

Here's a screenshot of the rules I have for the cell but it doesn't seem to be working?

Could it have anything to do with my formula for J5? It is =IF(H15="Duplex", "200", IF(H15="SFR", "100"))